# Clear and Unset doesn't free memory

Tags: memory, clear, assignment

Example: Try this example only if you have > 4G ram

```
d = 2000; 
f[x_, y_, d_] = 
     Sum[Subscript[a, i, j]*x^i*y^j, 
       {i, 0, d - 1}, {j, 0, d - i}];
```

Then

```
Clear[f]
```

or

```
f[x_, y_, d_] =.
```

You will see that the memory usage is not reduced after calling `Clear` or using `Unset`.

***Question: How to free the memory when I don't need a function anymore which is already evaluated?***

Edit: I look at the memory usage in taskmgr under Windows OS. As the answers report that the memory is indeed reduce by using MemoryInUse to check it.

Comment: Try setting `$HistoryLength=0`. Then you'll not use additional memory for saving results of old computations (anything like `%1` won't work in this case).

Comment: @Ruslan, But I need to save the results for some later use, only to a certain point I don't need some old results anymore.

Comment: User, I don't understand; do you want to save the results to a file?

Comment: Not saving to a file. I need to use the result of `f` later at some point in the computation, and after that point, I don't need it anymore.

Comment: If you define `f` with `$HistoryLength=0`, it'll still remain defined until you `Clear` it. You just won't be able to access _output_ of any previous computed cells via `%n`, and "Show More" etc. buttons won't work.

Comment: @Ruslan, thanks. But a neat question still: Can one define `f` with `$HistoryLength=0`? It seems to me $HistoryLength is defined in the scope of a notebook or larger? What I mean is that can one change `$HistoryLength` several times in a notebook?

Comment: `$HistoryLength` only is about history, not variables you define. So, you can have any value for `$HistoryLength`, and you can still work with your variables as usual — only not have access to history of outputs. And yes, if you need, you can change `$HistoryLength` at any time.

Answer (score 5):

In version 7 I cannot confirm what you report.  With my default of `$HistoryLength = 3` I see:

```
d = 2000;
f[x_, y_, d_] = Sum[Subscript[a, i, j]*x^i*y^j, {i, 0, d - 1}, {j, 0, d - i}];

MemoryInUse[]

Clear[f]
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 774871544
>
> 454831808

With `$HistoryLength = 0` as suggested by [Ruslan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5208/ruslan):

> 774868608
>
> 14955736

---

Michael suggested using `Block` to set `$HistoryLength` but this doesn't actually work.  Instead his code functions by a different method: it never assigns the output of the `Sum` to `Out[]`, because that line returns `MemoryInUse[]`.  The same thing can be done with with `CompoundExpression`:

```
d = 2000;
f[x_, y_, d_] = Sum[Subscript[a, i, j]*x^i*y^j, {i, 0, d - 1}, {j, 0, d - i}]; 1;
MemoryInUse[]
Clear[f];
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 774872048
>
> 14957200

The key is:

```
expr; 1;
```

Now the value set for `Out[]` is `1` rather than `expr`.

You may wonder why `expr;` assigns anything to `Out[]` -- this is intended and useful behavior because you often want to suppress the output of a line and reference it in the line below using `%`.  `expr;` is short for `CompoundExpression[expr, Null]`, which is recognized and handled to set `Out[]` to the evaluated `expr` instead of `Null`.

Comment: I don't know what is my default `$HistoryLength`. I just look at the memory usage showed in taskmgr. After using MemoryInUse, it shows that the reduced memory is very little if I don't use `$HistoryLength`.

Comment: @user565739 If you didn't change it, your default is `Infinity`.

Comment: @user565739 You shouldn't use `taskmgr` is that doesn't show memory that is actually *in use* but rather that which the application hasn't released; it's not the same thing.  If another application needs the memory it should be available.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard well if an application hasn't released some memory, other apps can't access it (unless it's swapped out). But taskmgr shows memory used by apps + caches etc. (starting from windows vista), which will mislead you if you try to detect when an app releases some memory.